# WorkManager is not taking retry delay less than 10 seconds

Tags: android, android-jetpack, android-workmanager, workmanagers

I would like to add RETRY mechanism for `WorkManager (gradle dependency - implementation 'android.arch.work:work-runtime:1.0.1').`

I tried applying BackOff Policy with duration less than 10 second and even than the manager is retrying calling API after 10 second only.

**request.setBackoffCriteria(BackoffPolicy.LINEAR, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);**

Below is the logcat information:

```
2019-05-09 11:51:15.355 25247-25416/ I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result RETRY for Work [ id=2b41ed0d-3aaa-438f-8dda-ddc0e9ff0293, tags={ LoginWork, mobile.android.workers.LoginJobWorker } ]

2019-05-09 11:51:25.779 25247-25416/ I/WM-WorkerWrapper: Worker result RETRY for Work [ id=2b41ed0d-3aaa-438f-8dda-ddc0e9ff0293, tags={ LoginWork, mobile.android.workers.LoginJobWorker } ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi I believe the minimum back of time is set at 10 seconds according to the docs the back off time needs to be set between MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS and MAX_BACKOFF_MILLIS please see the docs [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/work/WorkRequest.html#MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS:kotlin.Long)

Comment: Hi, as per the doc, MIN_BACKOFF_MILLIS  is 10 seconds. Wanted to know if there is any way to set it less than 10 seconds?

Comment: No, sorry, that's isn't. That's why it's considered the minimum.